# A proof concerning eigenvalues of Matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have to prove that if $A \in \mathbb{C}^{nxn}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C},$ and $\lambda^* \in \mathbb{C}$ is such that $\mbox{det}(A-λ^*I)\neq 0,$ then $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$ if and only if ${1\over 
\lambda-\lambda^*} \in \sigma((A-\lambda^*I)^{-1}).$
The problem is also, that I do not know what does the * (in $\lambda^*$) means. 
Could you please help me?.

Comment: The star means complex conjugation. $(2+3i)^*=2-3i$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess that $\lambda^*$ means the complex conjugate of $\lambda$, but it's actually not needed in the proof.

Suppose $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$; then there is a vector $v\ne0$ such that $Av=\lambda v$. Since $\lambda^*\notin\sigma(A)$ by assumption, we have $\lambda\ne\lambda^*$.

Now
$$
(A-\lambda^*I)v=Av-\lambda^*v=\lambda v-\lambda^*v=(\lambda-\lambda^*)v
$$
that can also be written
$$
(A-\lambda^*I)^{-1}v=(\lambda-\lambda^*)^{-1}v
$$
which proves $(\lambda-\lambda^*)^{-1}\in\sigma((A-\lambda^*I)^{-1})$.

Try the converse, by assuming there is a vector $w\ne0$ with
$$
(A-\lambda^*I)^{-1}w=(\lambda-\lambda^*)^{-1}w
$$
and deducing there exists $v\ne0$ with $Av=\lambda v$.

Comment: Since conjugation is not used in your proof, it could just signify another variable.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Possibly.

Comment: Eventually I have grasped your idea. Thank you !